# Basic concept of interaction probability

Tags: experimental-physics, probability, interactions, particle-detectors

In William R. Leo's book(Techniques for Nuclear and Particle Physics Experiments) I could not understand the following:

- $P(x)=$probability of not having interaction after a distance $x$
- $w \delta x$=probability of having interaction between $x$ and $x+\delta x$
- then probability of not having interaction between $x$ and $x+\delta x$ is
  $P(x+\delta x)=P(x)(1-w \delta x)$
  How do we reach this step?

Answer (score 1):

The probability of not having interaction between $x$ and $x+\delta x$ is given by
$$ P(x+\delta x) = \text{(not having an interaction until $x$)}\cdot\text{(not having an interaction between $x$ and $\delta x$)}. $$

Probability needs to be normalised, so the total probability needs to sum to $1$:
$$ \underbrace{\text{(probability of having interaction)}}_{w\delta x} +  \text{(probability of not having interaction)}= 1$$
$$ \quad \Rightarrow \quad  \text{(probability of not having interaction)} = 1 - w\delta x.$$

Hence, the probability of not having interaction between $x$ and $x+\delta x$ is:
$$ P(x+\delta x)= \underbrace{\text{(not having an interaction until $x$)}}_{P(x)}\cdot\underbrace{\text{(not having an interaction between $x$ and $\delta x$)}}_{1-w\delta x} = P(x)(1-w\delta x). $$

Comment: Thank you so much! But I have just a doubt that P(x) is given to be the probability of interaction after a distance x and you have taken until x. Does it not make any difference?

Comment: ‘After a distance $x$’ and ‘until $x$’ mean the same thing. You start at $x_0$ and move by distance $x$.